# Using Powershell, how do I convert Azure AD Group members into a Json object (file) which I can then update?

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am wondering the best approach to create a single Powershell script that does the following:

1. Obtains the email addresses of AAD group members using the following method (or some other) and converts it into a Json object

```
$AADGroup = "ExampleGroup1"

Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $AADGroup | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select Mail | ConvertTo-Json
```

The output of the above looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Mail":  "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
        "Mail":  "user2@example.com"
    }
]
```

2. Now that's fine, but what if i want to update this Json file/object by adding a new User, let's say 'user3@example.com' that is taken as an element from a string array as follows?

```
$UserName = @('user3@example.com')
```

There is this approach, and I suppose also another approach possibly where you could add the new user as part of the query command before using the ConvertTo-Json? Not sure which one could work best.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose? Why do you want to manually edit the json?

Comment: Ok, so not manually update, but this PS script should take new users as parameters at execution. The array here is just a placeholder for that idea. Does that make sense?

Comment: so basically instead of the array, param (
    [String[]] $User
)

Comment: If you want to ask a question about how to parameterize a script/function to take user email addresses and do something with the corresponding user objects: _ask that question_, don't ask another unrelated question about JSON :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) invoked via the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (`&`) in order to output both the original users' addresses and the to-be-added ones, both as single-property objects with a `.Mail` property, and then convert the combined results to JSON:

```bash
& {
  param([string[]] $User)

  # Output the existing users (email addresses) as objects with a .Mail property.
  Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $AADGroup | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select-Object Mail

  # Convert the array of users (email addresses) to objects with a .Mail property.
  $User | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] @{ Mail = $_ } }

} -User @('user3@example.com', 'user4@example.com') | 
  ConvertTo-Json
```

Working only with objects and *then* converting to JSON is preferable to partially converting to JSON first, and then trying to update the JSON (something that PowerShell provides no direct support for).

Answer (score 0):

You could use and append to the object result. Something like this:

```
$UserMail = @('user3@example.com', 'user4@example.com')
$AADGroup = "ExampleGroup1"

$adMailList = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $AADGroup | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select Mail | ConvertTo-Json
foreach($mail in $UserMail){
    $adMailList += @{ Mail = $mail }
}
```

At the end, the result should be something like:

```
[
    {
        "Mail":  "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
        "Mail":  "user2@example.com"
    },
    {
        "Mail":  "user3@example.com"
    },
    {
        "Mail":  "user4@example.com"
    }
]
```

In case the result is not what you're looking for, because it seems to be adding a HashTable instead of an object, then you could simply replace the inner foreach for:

```
$adMailList += [PSCustomObject]@{ Mail = $mail }
```

And that should do it